# Segmentation fault from pop_front() in C++

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault

My problem is that I am getting a segmentation fault that occurs after I call "`processList.pop_front()`".  If I comment out "`processList.pop_front()`", a segmentation then occurs during the second iteration of the outermost for loop, after a `tt.pop_front()` call, after that inner for loop has gone through almost 5000 iterations.  I can't see what the problem is.  Any thoughts?

```
loopLimit = processList.size();

for(int i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++)
{
    tempProcess = processList.front();
    tt = tempProcess.memAccesses;
    cout << "process number " << i << "\n";

    while(!tt.empty())
    {
        t = tt.front();
        tt.pop_front();
        cout << "from processlist: " << t.instrType << "  " << t.instrAddr << "\n";
    }

    if(!processList.empty())
    {
        cout << "size is now: " << processList.size() << "\n";
        processList.pop_front();
    }

}
```

Comment: what is processList? how do you initialize it?

Comment: what does processList stores? how did you init it?

Comment: where is this code ? is it in a function ? a method (in that case, check that 'this' is not NULL in your debugger) ? and what does valgrind says ?

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to copy a process. But maybe in your case it's just info about a process.

Comment: It turns out there was a problem with a destructor of one of my classes.  That is the reason I was getting a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem and I solved it by adding an invalid value to the deque:

```
loopLimit = processList.size();

for(int i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++)
{
    tempProcess = processList.front();
    tt = tempProcess.memAccesses;
    cout << "process number " << i << "\n";

    tt.push_back(-1);  //I guess you don't have a -1 type, so you wont have colisions
    while( tt.front()!=-1)
    {
        t = tt.front();
        tt.pop_front();
        cout << "from processlist: " << t.instrType << "  " << t.instrAddr << "\n";
    }

    if(!processList.empty())


    {
        cout << "size is now: " << processList.size() << "\n";
        processList.pop_front();
    }

}
```

Probably you will have to adapt it a bit.
Is not a very nice solution, but it works.